# How display payment succeeded without return_url param in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I have one problem in integration Stripe into my React application. I use code from official Stripe documentation. It works expected. My question is how to check is payment succeeded without using return_url ? Am I required to use return url ? I found in Stripe documentation redirect: "if_required" option, but that doesnt make anything. I just get error problem in my console if I put this object in confirmPayment method. I would like have scenario is payment successfull that client navigate to some Confirmation page and to get message payment successfully.

App.jsx

```
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

import CheckoutForm from "./CheckoutForm";
import "./App.css";

// Make sure to call loadStripe outside of a component’s render to avoid
// recreating the Stripe object on every render.
// This is your test publishable API key.
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_51LmE9VAoYs2flpvClDqeh0f1vhaDUkBM0bRGaJgThjtaMd3PiPUGQOHjn9f7XW1HGgSQBvTq3xoLy9PovlWLPUnR0031srjgyb");

export default function App() {
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
    fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ items: [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }] }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
  }, []);

  const appearance = {
    theme: 'stripe',
  };
  const options = {
    clientSecret,
    appearance,
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {clientSecret && (
        <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
          <CheckoutForm />
        </Elements>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

CheckoutForm.jsx

```
import {
  PaymentElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

export default function CheckoutForm() {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe) {
      return;
    }

    const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
      "payment_intent_client_secret"
    );

    if (!clientSecret) {
      return;
    }

    stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
      switch (paymentIntent.status) {
        case "succeeded":
          setMessage("Payment succeeded!");
          break;
        case "processing":
          setMessage("Your payment is processing.");
          break;
        case "requires_payment_method":
          setMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
          break;
        default:
          setMessage("Something went wrong.");
          break;
      }
    });
  }, [stripe]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
      // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
        return_url: "http://localhost:3000",
      },
    });

    // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
    // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
    // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
    // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
    // redirected to the `return_url`.
    if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
      setMessage(error.message);
    } else {
      setMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element" />
      <button disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
        <span id="button-text">
          {isLoading ? <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div> : "Pay now"}
        </span>
      </button>
      {/* Show any error or success messages */}
      {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When using `redirect: 'if_required'`, then the return_url attribute becomes not required.

If no redirection is required then you need to wait for the confirmation from the method `stripe.confirmPayment` and check if there is an error in the response.

To do so, you can adapt your **CheckoutForm.jsx** file and adapt your function **handleSubmit** like below:

```
setIsLoading(true);

const response = await stripe.confirmPayment({
 elements,
 confirmParams: {
  },
 redirect: 'if_required'
});

if (response.error) {
 showMessage(response.error.message);
} else {
 showMessage(`Payment Succeeded: ${response.paymentIntent.id}`);
}

setIsLoading(false);
```

Also, if you want to get notified from your backend when a successful payment has occurred, you can set a webhook[1] and listen to this Stripe event `payment_intent.succeeded`[2]

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.succeeded

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true if using automatic payment methods. It's insane that Stripe seems to provide no consideration for the usecase of wanting to redirect only successful payments to a return URL and have all failed payments redirect back to the checkout page.